# convert character string with timezone to date in r

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, strptime

I have a vector of character strings looking like this. I want to convert them to dates. The characters for time-zone is posing trouble.

```
> a
    [1] "07/17/2014 5:01:22 PM EDT" "7/17/2014 2:01:05 PM PDT"  "07/17/2014 4:00:48 PM CDT" "07/17/2014 3:05:16 PM MDT"
```

If I use: `strptime(a, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z")` I get `[1] NA`

If i omit the "%Z" for time-zone, and use this:

`strptime(a, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "EST5EDT")` I get

`[1] "2014-07-17 17:01:22 EDT"`

Since my strings contain various time zones - PDT, CDT, EDT, MDT , I can't default all time zones to `EST5EDT`. One way to overcome is split the vector into different vectors for each time-zone, remove the letters PDT / EDT etc. and apply the right timezone with `strptime` - "EST5EDT" , "CST6CDT" etc. Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the date is always the first part of the elements of the character vector and it is always followed by the time, splitting the elements by the whitespaces is a possibility. If only the date is needed:

```
dates <- sapply(a, function(x) strsplit(x, split = " ")[[1]][1])
dates <- as.Date(as.character(dates), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2014-07-17" "2014-07-17" "2014-07-17" "2014-07-17"
```

If also the time is needed:

```
datetime <- sapply(a, function(x) paste(strsplit(x, split = " ")[[1]][1:3], 
                                 collapse = " "))
datetime <- strptime(as.character(datetime), format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
[1] "2014-07-17 17:01:22 CEST" "2014-07-17 14:01:05 CEST"
```

You can set a different timezone using the `tz` argument here.